# Images not in a fixed height and width in responsive for all resolutions

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, responsive

I have created a profile page which is using many images of different sizes. For making it responsive I used twitter bootstrap3. For image I used `img-circle m-t-xs img-responsive` but still images are not displaying in a fixed width and height like as shown below.

[image]

But it works when I add a fixed height and width for `.img-responsive` as shown below, but again I know that will harm when it comes to responsive design.

```
.img-responsive {
     height: 100px;
     width: 100px;
}
```

Also actual view was looking fine like as shown below
when I zoom in it is showing so many white spaces like as shown below

**Actual view**

[image]

**Zoom In View**

[image]

Can anyone please help me how to get all those images in a fixed height and width in responsive for all resolutions. Also how I to arrange those white spaces when I zoomin

My complete web page is available in the below plunker (ther I have not added fixed height or width for `.img-responsive` class, can test by adding that)

https://plnkr.co/edit/qIDGjikGDetKI4LFAtmK?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class="contact-box row">
    <a href="profile.html">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-4 text-center row">
        <div style="width: 100%; padding-top: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 0;">
          <div style="border-radius: 50%; position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; background-image: url('https://cdn2.thedogapi.com/images/SkatQTaEQ.gif'); background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="m-t-xs font-bold">House Name</div>
      </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
          <h3><strong>Tinkku Baby</strong></h3>
          <p><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> City Name</p>
          <address>
            <strong>Twitter, Inc.</strong><br>
              795 Folsom Ave, Suite 600<br>
              San Francisco, CA 94107<br>
              <abbr title="Phone">P:</abbr> (123) 456-7890
          </address>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```